# Менять кодировку только в случае необходимости

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8

Циклу приходит огромное число строк

Большинство приходит в нормальной кодировке

Но некоторые в виде "РЎС‚СЂРѕРёС‚РµР»СЊСЃС‚РІРѕ РґРµСЂРµРІСЏРЅРЅС‹С… РґРѕРјРѕРІ РёР· Р±СЂСѓСЃР° РїРѕРґ РєР»СЋС‡, РіРѕС‚РѕРІС‹Рµ РґРµСЂРµРІСЏРЅРЅС‹Рµ РґРѕРјР° РІ РњРѕСЃРєРІРµ"

Для того, чтобы данная строка приняла нормальный вид, нужно:

```
name = title.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251')
```

Делаю такие действия со строкой такого вида - и она становится нормальной.
Проблема в том, что нужно в цикле как-то определять, нужного она вида или нет... Если делать такие действия с каждой строкой, то большинство (которые и были нормальными) станут каракулями...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    win_name = unicode(title.encode('cp1251')) #если title нормального вида, эта строка вызовет исключение
    name = title.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251') #если исключения нет, кодируем
except UnicodeDecodeError: #если исключение есть - оставляем
    name = title
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    name = title
```